# Send notification to only one user using his Firebase Auth id

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I want to send notification using firebase to only one user and his token is saved in firebase batabase. I will retrieve data this token from database but how can send notification to that user.

```
 refForLeaveReq.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Here i want to send Notification to only one user and his id is 7bvftaksdyej2383dnd4jdbek4dksb3kdh
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

If someone know other technique to send notification rather than firebase he/she can tell me.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the the Firebase Auth uid as a target for FCM. You have to use the *registration token*.

What I would do is use Firebase DB, save the uid along with the token in a `push_tokens` node like:

```
push_tokens
    - <uid>: <registration_token>
```

Having only the corresponding users to read the tokens (like your server), and use it accordingly.

Comment: But how can I send notification using this token

Comment: Like I said in the answer, *you can't*.

Comment: where is that registration token found?